# What does "fetch" and "stop trying to make 'fetch' happen" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, expressions

cambridge gives 3 meanings of [fetch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fetch)

meaning 1:

> to go to another place to get something or someone and bring it, him,
>   or her back

meaning 2:

> to be sold for a particular amount of money

meaning 3:

> to hit someone with the hand

this [post](https://www.eonline.com/news/671561/we-finally-know-why-fetch-from-mean-girls-never-happened) says

> "'Fetch' hasn't happened because people still try to make it happen," he said. "If people are still gonna try to make it happen, it's not gonna happen. I think that's a good PSA to do. Stop trying to make fetch happen! It hasn't happened because you're trying to make it happen."
>
> ...
>
> So just apply that to the word "fetch" and we might make it happen in
>   the next 20 years or so.
>
> ...
>
> "To clear the record, it's not that I don't want to have a Mean Girls
>   reunion," he insisted. "I'm just tired about everyone asking about it.
>   Because if I knew, you would know. It's not that I don't want there to
>   be a reunion. It's just I don't know when, so that's what I always
>   say. Mean Girls reunions are like 'fetch.'"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is confusing isn't it.

This is a reference to popular culture - in particular it's a quote referencing the Film 'Mean Girls'

In this context one of the girls was trying to introduce 'Fetch' as an adjective - equivalent perhaps to how we say something is 'cool'.  Another of the "Mean Girl's" tells her "Fetch isn't going to happen" meaning "You will not get people to introduce Fetch as an adjective".

It makes absolutely no sense without the contextual reference.

Comment: Apparently it's the opposite of sus now: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309144/what-does-sus-mean-in-the-sentence-people-who-joined-facebook-after-2017-are